# How can I use c++17 library inside C++14 project?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, c++14

I have a huge project written by C++14 works fine, now I want to add a 3rd-party library ([mcap](https://github.com/foxglove/mcap)) which will only compile under C++17. My question is how can i combine them together in my current C++14 project using CMake?

Currently I use PIMPL idiom to fix this, by creating a C++14 style header file and a static library, I can call the inner `CMakelists.txt` by `add_subdirectory` and link the `.a` file while builing the binary. Is there another way like `target_compile_features` in CMake to allow me compile a single file with `-std=c++17` and get a `.o` file as it normally would?

Comment: Most C++14 code compiles just fine under C++17.  Have you tried doing the whole project as C++17?

Comment: `set_target_properties(${THE_CPP17_LIB} PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17` to compile a single target as C++17. The header still needs to be compatible ofc.

Comment: @TimRoberts You are right, it works! Should be an answer.

Comment: "...which will only compile under."    ... under C++17 ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah, under c++17, my bad.